# Italicise part of a title with an non-flextable object

Tags: r, ggplot2, flextable, patchwork

I'm trying to add the name of a species in italics to my `patchwork` title, but I can't figure out how to do it, I keep getting an error message telling me that `italic()` only supports flexible objects.

Any ideas ?

```
species <- c("Castanea sativa")
plot_title <- substitute(paste("Ex title", italic(x), sep=" "), list(x=species))

library(patchwork)
patchwork <- p1 | (p2/p3/p4) +
   plot_annotation(
   title = plot_title,
   theme = theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face="bold", hjust = 0.5)))

p <- wrap_elements(patchwork)
p

Error in italic("Castanea sativa") : 
  Function `italic()` supports only flextable objects.
```

Comment: I'm not sure about patchwork's `title = `, but for `ggplot2` I'd use the format: `main = substitute("Ex title" ~ italic(x), list(x=species)))` - might be worth trying.

Comment: For `plot_annotation()` is  `title =`, not `main =`.

Comment: Does that syntax work with `title =` ?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen yes, when I don't italicise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I installed `patchwork` to test this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
word <- 'italics'
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 10:1)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()

p1 + p2 + plot_annotation(title = substitute("Ex title" ~ italic(x), list(x=word)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you. I thought I'd tried it with this code but apparently I was missing something, thanks.

Comment: I do note that package `flextable` has its own `italic()` function - it may be that loading it is masking the plotmath formatting.  Did you clear your R session before trying my suggestion?

Comment: I've tried, It seems to work even without the package `flextable`

Comment: Yes - I think loading flextable might actually impair it.

Comment: Indeed, this may be the problem I had, loading the package